# Extract element of given subclass from list of superclass

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Given this code

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class Cat extends Animal{}
class Pitbull extends Dog{}

object MyClass {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val animals: List[Animal] = List(new Dog(), new Cat(), new Pitbull(), new Dog(), new Cat())
        getElementOftype(animals, PitBull)
    }
    
    def getElementOftype(list: List[Animal], givenType: ???): Animal = {
        
    }
}
```

I want to extract the first element of type Pitbull from this List, How should I proceed with this?

What I tried but feels wrong

```
trait Identity{
    def who: String
}

class Animal extends Identity{
    override def who = "Animal"
}


class Dog extends Animal with Identity{
    override def who = "Dog"
}


class Cat extends Animal with Identity{
    override def who = "Cat"
}

class Pitbull extends Dog with Identity{
    override def who = "Pitbull"
}


object MyClass {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val animals: List[Animal] = List(new Dog(), new Cat(), new Pitbull(), new Dog(), new Cat())
        println(getElementOftype(animals, new Pitbull()))
    }
    
    def getElementOftype(list: List[Animal], givenType: Animal): Option[Animal] = {
        list.collectFirst{case s if s.who == givenType.who => s}
    }
}
```

I want to simply pass `Pitbull` as a parameter instead of instantiating an empty object.

This one works but I don't think it's the best approach.
There must be a more scalaesque way to do this.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working?

Comment: @GaëlJ I added the code that I used as a workaround.

Comment: In general, you should avoid being in this situation. When it is absolutely necessary the `ClassTag` works if you do not have problems with type erasure, otherwise you may need something more advanced like **Shapeless** or `TypeTag` or your own **typeclass**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this (not tested, there may be some typos):

```scala
def getElementOftype[A <: Animal](list: List[Animal])(implicit ct: ClassTag[A]): Option[A] = {
  list.collectFirst { case s: A => s }
}
```

The `ClassTag` is necessary to be able to match on the `A` type in `collectFirst`.

Comment: I should use the function as `getElementOftype(animals)(Pitbull)` ?

Comment: `getElementOftype[Pitbull](animals)`

Comment: You can also explicit pass a `Class` as a 2nd parameter if you prefer but it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks, the code works perfectly. I had to use `scala.reflect` and was just wondering if this will have any performance implications since I've been warned about it. I'm not familiar with reflection so I can't determine it on my own

Comment: I'm not an expert but ClassTag are provided at compile time. There should not be a runtime cost AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

when you write `Animal extends Identity` you mean Animal IS an Identity, which is wrong, using this approach is preferred:

```
class Animal { self: Identity => 
}
```

which means whenever you want to instantiate an Animal, you need to give an Identity to it, but why would you want to do that?
You can simply use pattern matching to filter required type like this:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def getElementsOfType[A <: Animal : ClassTag](animals: List[Animal]): Option[A] = {
  animals.filter {
    case a: A => true
    case _ => false
  }.map(_.asInstanceOf[A]).headOption
}
```

headOption is because your api returns Option[A] as result, you can make it return List[A] and get rid of the headOption in case you have multiple Pitbull's inside the list :)

Comment: this will not work. Read about type erasure.

Comment: @sarveshseri online results [here!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lOnKWSVURESb3DRfhpO6EA)

Comment: You are getting that because the first element is `Dog`. Try changing your input to `val list: List[Animal] = List(new Cat())`. Scastie itself is giving you that `abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` warning. Also why would you use a `filter` + `map` + `headOption` combination which will iterate over the list even after finding the required element and this being inefficient.

Comment: better use `find` or `collectFirst` instead of this `filter + map + headOption` thing.

Comment: In this case that's right, but my point was the self type thing and the ability to return List[A] instead of Option[A] in case there are more than 1 Pitbull's in the list